# Fragments Intercommunication

Tags: java, android

I have three Tabs implemented by using ActionBar. 
Fragments are coded programatically.

I want to set listener on Fragment2 (Tab2) so that when Fragment1 sends some data by callback (Custom listener), Fragment2 updates its content fields.

I couldn't figure out a way to do it, would appreciate help.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is likely to be to do it via the Activity. So when a fragment handles an event, it informs the Activity, the Activity then decides what to do with it, and passes it on to one of the other Fragments.

I'd suggest avoiding sending messages directly between Fragments, as the Activity is what knows which are currently in use.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options here.

Have your containing activity manage the actions performed - so have the activity implement a callback interface defined by your fragment and cast your activity to that callback in `onAttach()`:

```
private MyListener mListener

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
  try {
    mListener = (MyListener) activity;
  }
  catch (ClassCastException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Calling activity must implement MyListener");
  }
}
```

Or alternately, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle an intent broadcast by the first fragment:

```
public class MyFragment1 extends Fragment {

  public static final String ACTION_UPDATE = "com.example.MyFragment.update"

  public void updateOther() {
    Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE);
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(i);
  }
  ...
}

public class MyFragment2 extends Fragment {
  private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (intent.getAction().equals(MyFragment1.ACTION_UPDATE)) {
        // Do stuff
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    IntentFilter if = new IntentFilter(MyFragment1.ACTION_UPDATE);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, if);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that your onReceive call may or may not operate in the UI thread (and you'd really rather it didn't), so if you do any UI manipulation, do it in a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or you'll get an exception

Comment: I'm also interested on this. Why is it more complicated using Broadcasts?

Comment: It's just more code to write and you have to manage the lifecycle of your BroadcastReceivers - but it does keep your activity out of data management and leaves that to the fragments, making your activity code cleaner and more relevant - If you want I'll add the example